# Xamarin exception when loading .axml fles

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am recieving the following exception whenever trying to load a .axml file. Even after reinstalling VS2017:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An 
existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly 
closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 
size, 
SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 
size)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 
size)
```

Has anyone every experienced this issue?

Comment: Even if you create a blank app still have this exception?

Comment: @YorkShen Yes, this is happening from a blank App.

Comment: Which device was you deployed? real device, virtual device or remote device?

Comment: @YorkShen virtual device. I decided to go back to VS 2015, the issue is now gone.